# How to build a relational Java object model over a not-that-relational data model?

Tags: java, database, postgresql

I am currently working on several solutions to redesign a web application based on a database that is shared between this application and other running services.

The actual application uses NodeJS, and basically processes data after having exctracted too much information from a table in the database. I think this is wrong, because we should only ask the database for the data we need, and limit processing on the server as these processes imply long loading time for end users.
So I thought I would build a Java API instead, that would use objects that can be easily used by the front part of the application, and use Hibernate or an equivalent component to extract necessary information from database.

But the problem is that the database over which I would build this API, while supposed to be relational (it's postgreSQL), is actually composed of tables that do not communicate between each other : there are no joins between tables, hence no cascade on modifiying related objects. Furthermore, the tables do not correspond directly to objects used in the application. They are more like "super objects" that would contain other sub-objects in a Java model.

Problem is, I cannot recreate a "cleaner" database as it is used by other services (which is probably why it is so weirdly organised, by the way). I should use it as it is, and map the redesigned application to it. I could be allowed to redesign some tables to make them "more relational", but this should have no implications for the other services. That would imply to drastically rewrite some SQL functions, and I am not sure that it is a very efficient solution. That being say, I am not very experienced on writing SQL functions, so maybe that could be a solution in the end.

So, to put it all in a nutshell, what could I do to build an object oriented model using Java, or any other technology that you could think of, to redesign properly the application, without throwing the database or modifying it drastically ?

Any suggestion or lead of research would be greatly appreciated. Also, please tell me if I am not being precise enough, and I will try to improve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) to map your database records into entities.

[This wiki page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Advanced) gives quite a few samples of advanced uses :

- multiple tables for an entity :

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
  @SecondaryTable(name="EMP_DATA",
                  pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="EMP_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
                 )
  public class Employee {
      ...
      @Column(name="YEAR_OF_SERV", table="EMP_DATA")
      private int yearsOfService;

      @OneToOne
      @JoinColumn(name="MGR_ID", table="EMP_DATA", referencedColumnName="ID")
      private Employee manager;
      ...
  }
  ```
- multiple kind of entities in single table (this sample is mine, there was no code on the wiki ; let's hope I didn't mess it up !) :

  ```
  @Inheritance
  @DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISCRIMINATING_COLUMN")
  @Table(name="SOME_TABLE")
  public class Generic { ... }

  // only maps records from SOME_TABLE where DISCRIMINATING_COLUMN=SOME_VALUE
  @Entity
  @DiscriminatorValue("SOME_VALUE")
  public class firstSpecificType { ... } 

  // only maps records from SOME_TABLE where DISCRIMINATING_COLUMN=OTHER_VALUE
  @Entity
  @DiscriminatorValue("OTHER_VALUE")
  public class secondSpecificType { ... }
  ```
- entities from proc calls :

  ```
  // This stored procedure returns a result set and has one input parameter.
  @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
      name = "ReadAddressById",
      resultClasses = Address.class,
      procedureName = "READ_ADDRESS",
      parameters = {
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode=javax.persistence.ParameterMode.IN, name="P_ADDRESS_ID", type=Long.class)
      }
  )
  @Entity
  public class Address {
    ...
  }
  ```
- and many others.

Comment: Downvoter, tell me why you downvoted and I might be able to improve my answer ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll make some research to see if JPA can solve my problems -from what I see, it is what I was looking for.
I cannot upvote you because of my reputation though, but your answer is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: @Pikuni no problem. I think you'll be able to accept my answer as a solution to your question whatever your reputation is. Take your time to make sure it works for you though :)

Comment: I just accepted your answer as it seems to me that JSP will help me with the redesign of the application. I have actually used JSP in the past, but only for mapping data from several tables into one object. I did not know that you could do all this with it.Now you have gotten me curious. I will investigate about all these JSP possibilities.
Many thanks for your help and your advice. :)

Comment: @Pikuni You're welcome, good luck ! Also JPA not JSP, but you know that ;)